# Can an on buy effect move the bought card?

Tags: dominion

As I understand it, you buy a card, and that subsequently triggers a gain for non-Event cards. Am I correct in assuming, then, that an on-buy effect could not move a card due to it not being under your control yet?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR;** there are "When-Buy" effects that move cards from the supply, but there will never probably be an effect that moves a specific, just-bought, card.

I've had an extensive discussion with Donald X. Vaccarino, the designer, on discord before answering here. To thoroughly answer to your question, the following aspects have to be clarified first:

1. When you buy a card, you pay for the "name" of the card and not a physical copy of it. The physical copy comes as a consequence of buying it.
2. There will probably never be an effect that moves a just-bought card, because you don't buy a specific physical card.

These are clarified in subsequent sections with the related sources.

### Current when-buy effects

There are currently no "when-buy" effects that move a specific just-bought card, as of the time of writing this reply (before [Dominion: Nocturne](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Nocturne)). Here is [a comprehensive list of all "when buy" events](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Triggered_effects#When_you_buy_a_card). Most likely, there will never be an effect in the lines of "*when you buy this, move it to ...*", because it will be too confusing. This will become clear in a subsequent example.

### Owning a card before you gain it

According to the [Inheritance FAQ](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Inheritance), as @Gendolkari also mentioned, when you buy a card, you own it immediately. Here is how buying an [Estate](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Estate) works, if you have inherited [Noble Brigand](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Noble_Brigand):

1. You declare that you are buying an Estate and pay for it.
2. The Estate that you are going to gain now is yours, thus it immediately inherits the Noble Brigand's text.
3. The "when-buy" activates and you attack every other player.
4. Then, you gain the top Estate card from the Estate pile to your discard pile.

### How Buying works

When declaring "*I am buying card X*", you do not pay to buy and gain the topmost card of that name at the time of paying, but the **topmost card of that name after all "when-buy" effects have been resolved**. You are essentially buying an **abstract card**. Sadly, there is a no clear writing of this exact mechanism. Source: DXV on Dominion Discord channel, at 2017-08-27, 18:00 UTC+02:00.

For your information, here is the order of events: (summarizing from [Base rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=2011), p. 5, "Buy Phase", [Hinterlands rules](http://riograndegames.com/getFile.php?id=579), p. 4, "Additional Rules")

1. You choose a card to buy and pay for it.
2. No cards have been moved from the supply yet.
3. Any "when-buy" events are now triggered, which might move cards (*Port*, *Messenger*).
4. You now gain the top card of that pile, with the name of the card you paid for, to your discard pile (unless otherwise stated).
5. Any "when-would-gain" events are now triggered.
6. The card moves to its final destination (e.g., discard pile) and it's gained.
7. Any "when-gain" events are now triggered.

This will become clear with the notorious Messenger example.

### Messenger example

TL;DR; in a 2-player game, if there are 2 Messengers left in the supply, you buy Messenger and name "Messenger", you will only gain one, not both. This is how the official digital implementation is working.

Suppose that in a 2-player game, there are at least 3 Messengers left in the Messenger pile: *Messenger A*, *Messenger B* and *Messenger C*, in that order, with Messenger A being the top card. Here is what happens when you buy a Messenger and choose Messenger for the "when-buy" effect:

1. You spend $4 to buy a Messenger.
2. "When-Buy" ability triggers; you name "Messenger".
3. Due to step (2), you gain *Messenger A* from the Messenger pile (the top one).
4. Since step (3) was successful (e.g., no *Trader* was revealed), then every other player gains a Messenger; your opponent gains *Messenger B*.
5. "When-Buy" ability ends.
6. Due to buying a Messenger in step (1), you now gain a Messenger from the Messenger pile; *Messenger C* is moved to your discard pile.

Here's what happens if there are only 2 Messengers in the Messenger pile:

6. Due to buying a Messenger in step (1), you now gain a Messenger from the Messenger pile and **fail**, as there are no more Messengers there.

### Talisman Example

You play a [Talisman](http://wiki.dominionstrategy.com/index.php/Talisman) and buy a Ruined Village. Let's name *Ruined Village A* the top card. Here is the order of events:

1. You spend one buy and $0 to buy a Ruined Village.
2. The "when-buy" of Talisman is triggered, because Ruined Village costs up to $4 and is not a victory card.
3. You gain *Ruined Village A* from the supply, due to the "when-buy" effect in step (2).
4. Now, you gain a Ruined Village because you bought one in step (1).

   - If the next card is *Ruined Village B*, then you gain that one.
   - Otherwise, if the next card is *Ruined Market*, you gain nothing.

Note that in the last case you failed to gain a Ruined Village after buying one. The one you gained was from the "when-buy" effect. However, this effect did not move the specified card you were about to gain; it just instructed you to gain another copy of it.

As you can see, there are "when-buy" effects that move cards from the supply (Messenger and Port). You first resolve any "When-Buy" effects and then gain the top card from the respective pile, if there is one. For this reason, I assume there will never (probably) be an effect in the lines of "*When you buy this, put it ...*", because it would be too confusing.

Comment: That was quite the explanation! Thanks for your response.

Comment: Are you a member of f.ds?

Comment: @GendoIkari Not yet, but I hang out on the Dominion channel on discord. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that when you buy a card, you then gain that card right after.  On-buy effects, such as Farmland and Noble Brigand, happen after you buy the card but before you gain it.

You are not correct that he card is not yours after you buy it but before you gain it. This is clarified in the Adventures rules in the FAQ for Inheritance. If you use Inheritance on an action that has a "when you buy this" effect; buying an Estate will trigger the effect, because the Estate becomes yours after you buy it, even though you haven't gained it yet.

There is no on-buy effect that moves the card you are buying. If there were, the card could be moved just fine; but it would become confusing / unclear when you go to gain the card, and it is no longer in the pile.

There is a similar effect that results in an interesting situation/rule. If you have a Talisman in play and you buy a card, Talisman's on-buy happens before you gain the card you bought. This means that you will gain the card on top of he pile due to Talisman first. THEN you will gain the next card due to the buy. This means that buying a card doesn't necessarily get you the card you bought! It gets you a card with the same name from the same pile.

Comment: In response to your last paragraph, is it possible that Talisman cancels your gaining of your bought card? I'm thinking in the situation that you buy a Ruined Village from the Ruins pile with a Talisman in play, Talisman gains the Ruined Village, and because the Ruins pile is random, there is no longer a Ruined Village for you to gain from buying it.

Comment: @user3105700 You play a Talisman and buy a Ruined Village; first you gain copy of the Ruined Village (the top card), due to the effect of the Talisman, as when-buy events happen before gaining. Then you gain a Ruined Village due to buying one; if the next card is not a Ruined Village, you will fail to do so.